# Is this an exponential family of distributions? from casella and berger 6.20

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I am trying to do 6.20 in Casella and Berger part d. The solutions manual says that the order statistics are minimal sufficient and not complete. I understand their logic, but why doesn't this work?

The distribution is $$f(x)=e^{-(x-\theta)}e^{-e^{-(x-\theta)}}$$ The range is $-\infty<x<\infty$  $-\infty<\theta<\infty$

I think this breaks into an exponential family with $$f(x)=e^{-x}e^{\theta}e^{-e^{-x}e^{\theta}}$$

And this would imply $\sum{e^{-x}}$ is complete sufficient. A quick computation makes me think its minimal as well. Am I correct?
The sample is $X_1, X_2....X_n$ iid from this distribution.

Comment: what does doing that show? minimality?

Comment: Thats not the same definition that my book has for sufficiency.

Comment: I wasn't really trying to show it that way anyway. I was first trying to prove exponential family and then use 6.2.25 and 6.2.10 in my book, which imply that if the exponential is $f(x)=h(x)c(\theta)exp(\sum{w(\theta)t(x)})$ then $\sum t(x) $ is complete and sufficient

Comment: you may have a point

Comment: Any update on this? I agree with the op

Comment: The only condition is that $\{e^\theta: \theta \in \Theta\}$ contain an open set in $\mathbb{R}$, which I believe is satisfied.

Comment: A complete sufficient statistics is automatically minimal.

Comment: Everything in the OP is correct. $\sum e^{-X_i}$ is a minimal complete sufficient statistic.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/790053/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/372537/321264