# Why this pdf is not exponential family? and thus not complete sufficient statistic?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

$ f(x | \theta) = e^{-(x-\theta)} \exp(-e^{-(x-\theta)}) , -\infty < x < \infty, -\infty < \theta <\infty $ , where I can identify $h(x)=e^{-x}, c(\theta)=e^\theta, w(\theta)=e^\theta, t(x)= -e^{-x}$ not an exponential family?

The definition of exponential family is
$ f(x | \theta) = h(x)c(\theta) \exp\left( \sum_{i=1}^{k} w_i(\theta)t_i(x) \right) $.

Then by using theorem complete statistics in the exponential family , since here $w_1(\theta)=e^\theta$ contains an open set in $\Bbb{R}^1$. Thus, my statistic $\sum_i (-e^{-x_i})$ is complete.

However, the answer showed that it is not complete by using ancillary method. Can anyone show me where my method got wrong?

Comment: Are you sure about the support of $x$? It seems to me that it depends in $\theta$, in order for $f(x|\theta)$ to be a valid pdf. In that case, you may recall that for a pdf to belong to the exponential family, its support should not be dependent on the parameter, i.e., $\theta$.

Comment: @Arash: Yes, the support of x doesn't depend on $\theta$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verify a distribution that is not exponential family](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372537/verify-a-distribution-that-is-not-exponential-family)

Comment: Your answer is correct.