# Extreme value distribution- member of the exponential family?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function, exponential-distribution

I am asked to prove whether or not the following distribution (extreme value distribution) is part of the exponential family:
$$ f_Y(y;\mu,\phi)=\frac{1}{\phi}\exp[-\frac{y-\mu}{\phi}+\exp(-\frac{y-\mu}{\phi})]$$
My definition of the exponential family is the following:
[image]

I have tried rewriting the density function and obtained:
$$f_Y(y;\mu,\phi)=\exp \left[\log\frac{1}{\phi}-\frac{y}{\phi}+\frac{\mu}{\phi}-\exp\left(\frac{-y+\mu}{\phi}\right)\right]$$
However, at this point I am stuck. How do I get the density function into the form of the exponential family distribution from this point? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3412441/321264) that this is a member of exponential family with natural parameter $\theta(\mu)=-e^{\mu/\phi}$ provided $\phi$ is known. So the answer to your question depends on $\phi$ being fixed or not.